# DeploymentPlanExecutor.OnExecute not Being Called By SqlPackage.exe

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, sqlpackage

I am trying write a PowerShell script to deploy a DACPAC that requires a specific DeploymentPlanExecutor extension that I have written. The extension implements override methods for both OnApplyDeploymentConfiguration and OnExecute.

Everything works fine when I deploy from the database project directly from Visual Studio 2017. However, when I try to deploy a DACPAC that uses the extension using SqlPackage.exe or using the DacServices class in the API, only the OnApplyDeploymentConfiguration for my extension is called. The deployment completes successfully without ever calling the OnExecute method.

I have the most up to date version of SSDT installed and I am running SqlPackage.exe from the installation under the Visual Studio 2017 directory. My extension is installed in the Extensions folder under the same directory structure.

I have verified that it is being loaded by the output messages it produces during the OnApplyDeploymentConfiguration as well as through breakpoints with a debugger attached. My breakpoint at the beginning of the OnExecute method is never hit.

Comment: have you set "dacDeployOptions.RunDeploymentPlanExecutors = true"?

Comment: @EdElliott That fixed the problem for both the DacServices API call and the SqlPackage.exe command. Thank you.